# What are the flash sizes of the different dd-wrt builds and can I downgrade to a lighter build?

Tags: router, memory, dd-wrt, flash, jfs

I wanted to upgrade my router so I bought a "new" DHP-1565 (16 mb flash 128 mb ram) to replace my old E1000 (4 mb flash 32 mb ram).
I flashed with the official firmware from the database which is 16 mb in size.
Now I want to run some scripts and software on the router (adblocker, file server, etc) which I want to install to jffs. Problem is that there is no more space available. Is it possible to "downgrade" to a lighter version?
I am currently using DD-WRT v24-sp2 (04/09/15) std (SVN revision 26653) and I'm assuming it's the mega edition.
What are the flash sizes of the other builds and can I "downgrade" to them?

Edit: fixed it with an old usb drive but I am still interested in the sizes of the different builds. I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: I've sometimes seen questions like this getting a very specific answer, e.g. specific to your router.  However, your first statement does tend to confuse things from the rest of your question (in my opinion).  Did you get that new router yet?  Are you trying to downgrade for the old router, or another one?

Comment: I've got the new router (DHP-1565) in my possession and I've flashed dd-wrt on it. This completely fills the flash memory of the router. I discovered that this is with good reason as this is a router specific firmware and without it you can't use the powerline feature. I have since used an old usb drive (formatted to ext2) mounted to /jffs/ to fix this memory issue. I am, however, still interested in knowing the sizes of the different builds (mini, micro, normal, mega etc) for future reference purposes since this will not be the last router I will flash and the time between flashes will b long